# Can't write to a readonly object exception is observed when upgraded jdk from 1.6 to jdk 1.7

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, maven, jboss

I am trying to migrate an existing application(which contains web Service) from JDK_1.6 to 1.7_79 and trying to deploy it into JBOSS 5.1 but stuck with the below exception and not able to find any solution. I am not able to figure out which read only object it is trying to update. I am facing this exception intermittently.The application works fine with jdk 1.6. 
Can someone please tell me about the problem...

The application is having below configuration

- apache-maven-2.2.1
- jboss-5.1.0.GA

Exception Trace:

```
2015-12-30 05:38:11,938 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (tomcat-exec-2) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator_2] TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple@67c3fd26
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:516)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:101)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:269)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:89)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1423)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:137)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:170)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at com.XYZ.framework.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:202)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:216)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1054.getPopulatedPrincipal(Unknown Source)
    at com.XYZ.login.UADLoginModule.getRoleSets(UADLoginModule.java:97)
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.AbstractServerLoginModule.commit(AbstractServerLoginModule.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:596)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.defaultLogin(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:552)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.authenticate(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:486)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.isValid(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:365)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManager.isValid(JaasSecurityManager.java:160)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:905)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:592)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.strategy.ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.lockItem(ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:74)
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.lockItem(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:504)
    ... 64 more
2015-12-30 05:38:12,325 INFO  [com.XYZ.method.audit] (tomcat-exec-9) About to call [validate in UADWebServiceClientImpl]
2015-12-30 05:38:12,327 INFO  [com.XYZ.method.audit] (tomcat-exec-9) About to call [getTTLUADWebServiceSoap in UADWSLookupHelper]
2015-12-30 05:38:12,327 INFO  [com.XYZ.method.audit] (tomcat-exec-9) Completed call to [getTTLUADWebServiceSoap in UADWSLookupHelper]
2015-12-30 05:38:12,325 INFO  [com.XYZ.uad.UADWebServiceClientImpl] (tomcat-exec-9) [?] validate request: UADValidateRequest{username=user4, password=****, applicationId=100029}
2015-12-30 05:38:12,327 INFO  [com.XYZ.uad.UADWebServiceClientImpl] (tomcat-exec-9) [?] inside callUADValidate in UADWebServiceClientImpl
2015-12-30 05:38:12,356 INFO  [com.XYZ.external.ws.FakeUad] (tomcat-exec-11) Fake UAD pretending to validate user4 returning UADResponse{value=1, userId=100254, message=Fake Validation Success, user4 will act as user id 100254}
2015-12-30 05:38:12,361 INFO  [com.XYZ.method.audit] (tomcat-exec-9) Completed call to [validate in UADWebServiceClientImpl]
2015-12-30 05:38:12,361 INFO  [com.XYZ.login.UADLoginModule] (tomcat-exec-9) Inside getRoleSets
2015-12-30 05:38:12,703 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (tomcat-exec-9) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator_2] TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple@6c68ef31
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:516)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:101)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1054.getPopulatedPrincipal(Unknown Source)
```

In the above EJB method which is in transaction scope, a hibernate entity configured with READ_ONLY second level cache seems to be made dirty (updated).
So post EJB method invocation updated hibernate entity is flushed, there it failed.

If you are not deliberately updating the entity, then please check whether you have something like this in entity's get/set methods.

```
String getProperty1() {
  return property1 != null ? property1 : "";
}
```

If you are not going to persist, update or remove entities in that ejb method then add following annotation..

```
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Comment: Thank you Sachidhanandhan. It worked for me when annotated the ejb methods with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)